# How to disable other touch gestures after adding another tap gesture to the view?

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view with some tables and buttons on it, and then I want to add a tap gesture to the entire view, but I only want that gesture recognizer to recognize taps.

Ideally, I want to do something when the added gesture recognizer is tapped, then remove that gesture recognizer after so the other buttons and tables can be accessed. Basically a tap to dismiss functionality that replicates something like the facebook notifications window, tap outside to dismiss, but not interfere with the buttons outside of the notifications view.

Can anybody help?

My current code is:

```
    NotificationsWindow *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"NotificationsWindow" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    customView.frame= CGRectMake(12, 12, customView.frame.size.width, customView.frame.size.height);

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizerForSubView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapBehindAgain:)];
    [recognizerForSubView setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    recognizerForSubView.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; //So the user can still interact with controls in the modal view
    [customView addGestureRecognizer:recognizerForSubView];


    [self.view addSubview:customView];

    [self catchTapForView:customView.superview];

(void)handleTapBehind:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"tapped");

    [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:sender];
}

     (void)dismissButton:(UIButton *)button {
        [button removeFromSuperview];
        [[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];

    }

    (void)catchTapForView:(UIView *)view {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = view.bounds;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [view addSubview:button];
    }
```

I want to make it so that the recognizer for the super view dismisses the subview, but not to interfere with the other taps on the super view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you describe is to overlay a transparent UIView that captures the touch. Simply remove it when touched.

You can use the following code:

```
- (void)dismissButton:(UIButton *)button {
    [button removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)catchTapForView:(UIView *)view {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = view.bounds;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view addSubview:button];
}
```

Call `catchTapForView` on your view. Do any additional handling in `dismissButton`.

Comment: Keep the active recognizer as a member and do removeGestureRecognizer.

Comment: I just added the code that I'm using, which works to dismiss, but still interferes with the code of the superview, i.e. pressing a button on the super view dismisses the subview but also goes and does what that button is supposed to do

Comment: the thing with this is that it will dismiss my subview as well, because the button's frame is the entire super view. or perhaps it is something wrong with my code, I have updated my first question with your edits...i need to have a gesturerecognizer/button around the subview. My solution of the gesturerecognizers worked in recognizing the two different taps, one of the subview and one of the superview, with no overlap, but it didnt solve the problem of overriding buttons on the superview until the subview was dismissed. your solution overrides the buttons on the superview, but doesnt isolate

Comment: @HudsonBuddy When you use the methods above you do not need to use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. The button replaces that functionality. The problem is that you do `[[self.view.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];`in two places now.

Comment: oh ok, i was adding the custom view first, because then i would know about the superview so that i could use your method and pass the super view to it to add the button, but i found a work around to find the super view before adding the subview and added the button first, and then the custom view, so now the subview covers the button and not the other way around, it works as desired now thanks for the help